# React Native expo - How to show screen only once with AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am trying to show my 'Create ProfileScreen' only once for first time app users.
However it doesn't seem to behave as desired, I am thinking maybe it's due to my logic, I would really appreciate help with. Here is my logic and code below:

**Loading Screen**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

export default LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const value = AsyncStorage.getItem('FirstTime')

    return navigation.navigate(value === null ? 'Register' : 'HomeScreen')

}
```

**Profile Context**

```
const saveLogin = async () => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('FirstTime', 'true')
            alert('saved')
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

const removeLogin = async () => {
        try {

            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('FirstTime')
            alert('Removed')

        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }
```

**Profile Screen**

After completing in the profile form, you `submit` and the `value` is set from 'null' to 'true'. So when I reload the app, it always takes me to the homepage, even after I removed the value or set it to 'null'.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{onSubmit(),()=>saveLogin()}}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontWeight: '500' }}>Submit</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Giovanni Esposito I managed to find a solution.
I used `getItem` in the loading screen and `setItem` in the CreateProfile screen. and worked perfectly. Thank you :D

```
export default LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        load()
    }, [])

    const load = async () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('FirstTime').then(result => {
            if (result !== null) {
                navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
            } else {
                navigation.navigate('Register')
            }
        })

    }

    return <ActivityIndicator />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, also `AsyncStorage.getItem` is async. So you could do something like:

```
import { AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'

export default LoadingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    
    componentDidMount() {
       AsyncStorage.getItem('FirstTime', (result) => {
          navigation.navigate(result === null ? 'Register' : 'HomeScreen')
       })
    }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Giovanni for help, however, I am getting an `Error: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or render nothing, return null.`

Comment: @jonson.ncube Ok, maybe I understood your problem. You could return an `ActivityIndicator` while `AsyncStorage` is loading data from chace and then navigate into `Register` or `HomeScreen`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try the same code using hooks, I am not so good with class components :D.